# Maven dependencies rest project

Tags: rest, jersey, dependencies

In my rest project I am using jersey 1.8. I want to upgrade to jersey 1.18 but this broke my project when I try to launch it again in server.
Here is my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>BoardGame</groupId>
<artifactId>BoardGame</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
     <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet/mimepull 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet</groupId>
        <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I want to use multipart 1.18 instead of 1.8.

When I run project on server I am getting this error : 
 Servlet /BoardGame threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

Could anyone help me with this?

Stack trace :

> Apr 15, 2017 11:19:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   loadOnStartup SEVERE: Servlet /BoardGame threw load() exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Why aren't you updating the version of **all** the Jersey dependencies?

Comment: I tried to update only the jersey multipart dependency from 1.8 to 1.18 but it doesn't work and I an error : com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException.

So I tried to update all jersey dependencies' version.

Comment: But you didn't. Two are the old version and two are the new version. Update _all_ of them

Comment: Post the whole stack trace